# vue.js: toggle method changing the value, but no behaviour is changed in view

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

If I click on one of the list (that satisfies toggle function condition)  then it should do show or not show a dropdown menu. So far the method toggle changes the value of dropDownOpen inside chrome console, but no changes are shown in the view, code:

The console shows the value changing and it is not changed in the template!

```
 <ul>
          <li v-for="(navHeading, index) in headerMenuItems" @click="toggle(navHeading.name)" :class="{'open': dropDownOpen}">
            <icon :glyph="navMenuIconNames[index]" :viewBox="navMenuIconNames[index].viewBox" :height="25" :width="50"></icon>
            <a class="navigation-title" href="#">{{ navHeading.name }}</a>
            <ul class="drop-down-menu">
              <li v-for="dropDownMenuItem in navHeading.children">
                <a class="drop-down-menu-item-title">{{ dropDownMenuItem.name }}</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
</ul>
```

script:

```
 data() {

      const dropDownOpen = false
      return { dropDownOpen }
    },
methods: {
      toggle: (dropDownName) => {
        if (dropDownName === 'Meer') {
          this.dropDownOpen = !this.dropDownOpen
        }
        console.log(this.dropDownOpen)
        return this.dropDownOpen
      }
    }
```

CSS:

```
<style scoped>
  .open .drop-down-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: tomato;
  }

  .drop-down-menu {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` in your method is not pointing to the vue instance, so use a normal function instead of fat arrow function

```
methods: {
  toggle: function(dropDownName) {
    if (dropDownName === 'Meer') {
      this.dropDownOpen = !this.dropDownOpen
    }
    console.log(this.dropDownOpen)
    return this.dropDownOpen
  }
```

See the [warning](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods) why you should not use `=>` arrow functions with methods

add `v-show` attribute like this in your template.

```
<ul v-show="dropDownOpen" class="drop-down-menu">
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not know exactly but this worked:

```
 methods: {
      toggle(dropDownName) {
        if (dropDownName === 'Meer') {
          this.dropDownOpen = !this.dropDownOpen
        }
        return this.dropDownOpen
      }
    },
```

and template:

```
 <ul>
      <li v-for="(navHeading, index) in headerMenuItems" @click="toggle(navHeading.name)">
        <icon :glyph="navMenuIconNames[index]" :viewBox="navMenuIconNames[index].viewBox" :height="25" :width="50"></icon>
        <span>{{ dropDownOpen }}</span>
        <a class="navigation-title" href="#">{{ navHeading.name }}</a>
        <ul v-show="dropDownOpen" class="drop-down-menu">
          <li v-for="dropDownMenuItem in navHeading.children">
            <a class="drop-down-menu-item-title">{{ dropDownMenuItem.name }}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: This is because i forgot to mention `v-show` attribute. But the script should work.